# Using keyListener and textChangedListener together in Android editText

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am trying to use both

```
editPhoneNumber.setKeyListener(new KeyListener()
```

and

```
editPhoneNumber.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()
```

together but it seems that they block eachother, my editText is no longer editable.

Thanks for any help

Edit:

I am trying to format the input as the user types:

Input:5551112233
Formatted Input: (555) 111 22 33

The formatting part works well but the reason I am trying to add the KeyListener is when the user tries to delete (by pressing on delete key) and when the inputs length becomes -let's say- 12 characters TextChangedListener interrupts the user to delete by always putting a " " at he end of the text. That is why I am trying to disable the TextChangedListener when the input is a delete key.

```
boolean isResetClicked;
EditText editPhoneNumber;
Button buttonReset;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    editPhoneNumber = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editPhoneNumber);
    buttonReset = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonResetPhoneNumber);
    buttonReset.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            isResetClicked = true;
            editPhoneNumber.getText().clear();
            isResetClicked = false;
        }
    });

    editPhoneNumber.setKeyListener(new KeyListener()
    {

        @Override
        public boolean onKeyUp(View view, Editable text, int keyCode,
                KeyEvent event)
        {
            if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL)
            {
                isResetClicked = true;
            }
            else
                isResetClicked=false;
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onKeyOther(View view, Editable text, KeyEvent event)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onKeyDown(View view, Editable text, int keyCode,
                KeyEvent event)
        {

            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public int getInputType()
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public void clearMetaKeyState(View view, Editable content,
                int states)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });

    editPhoneNumber.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()
    {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                int count)
        {
            String str;

            if (!isResetClicked)
            {
                if (s.length() == 0)
                {
                    editPhoneNumber.setText("(");
                }
                if (s.length() == 1)
                {
                    str = editPhoneNumber.getText().toString();
                    editPhoneNumber.setText("(" + str);
                    editPhoneNumber.setSelection(editPhoneNumber.getText()
                            .length());
                }
                if (s.length() == 4)
                {
                    str = editPhoneNumber.getText().toString();
                    editPhoneNumber.setText(str + ") ");
                    editPhoneNumber.setSelection(editPhoneNumber.getText()
                            .length());
                }
                if (s.length() == 9)
                {
                    str = editPhoneNumber.getText().toString();
                    editPhoneNumber.setText(str + " ");
                    editPhoneNumber.setSelection(editPhoneNumber.getText()
                            .length());
                }
                if (s.length() == 12)
                {
                    str = editPhoneNumber.getText().toString();
                    editPhoneNumber.setText(str + " ");
                    editPhoneNumber.setSelection(editPhoneNumber.getText()
                            .length());
                }

            }

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
        {
        }
    });
```

Edit 2:

Even if I'm still unable to understand why two event listeners block my edittext, I solved my problem by modifying the code:

```
@Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                int count)
        {
            String str;
            /*Log.i("ED",
                    "LengthBefore before (lengthBefore = lengthAfter;): "
                            + String.valueOf(lengthBefore));*/
            lengthBefore = lengthAfter;
            lengthAfter = s.length();
            /*Log.i("ED",
                    "LengthBefore after (lengthBefore = lengthAfter;): "
                            + String.valueOf(lengthBefore));*/
            if ((lengthBefore < lengthAfter) || lengthBefore == 0)
            {
                if (!isResetClicked)
                {
                    if (s.length() == 0)
                    {
                        editPhoneNumber.setText("(");
                    }
                    if (s.length() == 1)
                    {
                        str = editPhoneNumber.getText().toString();
                        editPhoneNumber.setText("(" + str);
                        editPhoneNumber.setSelection(editPhoneNumber
                                .getText().length());
                    }
                    if (s.length() == 4)
                    {
                        str = editPhoneNumber.getText().toString();
                        editPhoneNumber.setText(str + ") ");
                        editPhoneNumber.setSelection(editPhoneNumber
                                .getText().length());
                    }
                    if (s.length() == 9)
                    {
                        str = editPhoneNumber.getText().toString();
                        editPhoneNumber.setText(str + " ");
                        editPhoneNumber.setSelection(editPhoneNumber
                                .getText().length());
                    }
                    if (s.length() == 12)
                    {
                        str = editPhoneNumber.getText().toString();
                        editPhoneNumber.setText(str + " ");
                        editPhoneNumber.setSelection(editPhoneNumber
                                .getText().length());
                    }

                }
            }
            lengthAfter = s.length();
            /*Log.i("ED", "LengthAfter after (lengthAfter = s.length();): "
                    + String.valueOf(lengthAfter));
            Log.i("ED", "LengthBefore: " + String.valueOf(lengthBefore));
            Log.i("ED", "LengthAfter: " + String.valueOf(lengthAfter));*/

        }
```

As when the user tries to delete a character the new length will be shorter than the older one. So I prevented the code from checking the length by:

```
if ((lengthBefore < lengthAfter) || lengthBefore == 0)
```

Comment: Do you have any more sample code? What are your key listener and text changed listener doing that makes you think they are blocking each other?

Comment: Solved it in another way, check Edit 2 pls.